# Is it possible to lappend to a list in a list held in array directly without using a temporary variable?

Tags: tcl

In the code below, is there anyway to get the same result without using the temporary variable `x`?

It appears that `lappend` will not update a list unless held in a variable and I don't know how to get something like `[lindex comPorts($sock) 4]` versus `[lindex $comPorts($sock) 4]`, which doesn't work because is a value not stored in a variable.

Thank you.

```
set sock abc
set comPorts($sock) [list $sock 0 0 1 {129} {} {} {} ]
set data {134 135}
chan puts stdout [lindex $comPorts($sock) 4]
# => 129
set x [lindex $comPorts($sock) 4]
chan puts stdout [lappend x {*}$data]
# => 129 134 135
chan puts stdout [lset comPorts($sock) 4 $x]
# => abc 0 0 1 {129 134 135} {} {} {} ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the data elements one by one in a loop:

```
foreach n $data {lset comPorts($sock) {4 end+1} $n}
```

If the data list is long, you may prefer to use `linsert` to build the sublist:

```
lset comPorts($sock) 4 [linsert [lindex $comPorts($sock) 4] end {*}$data]
```

Comment: Thank you. It's hard to understand what is really going on when using lists, dictionaries, and arrays. A list seems like a common numerically indexed array but when try to set a nested element, it seems that it is manipulating strings all the time and then overwriting the previous data or allocating new memory for a new string. Many list methods return the entire list again. I was confused for a couple hours messing with `dict with` until I saw in my books that the values are held in shadow variables and not updated until after the block completes. It appears inefficient but still runs fast.

Comment: Why does your `foreach` code wrok? Ousterhout's text reads that `the lset` command cannot create new list elements and your setting index `end+1`. It that not a new list element? Perhaps it is a change since the book which is 2010 and preceded Tcl 8.6.

Comment: This functionality was introduced in Tcl 8.6 with [tip 331](https://core.tcl-lang.org/tips/doc/trunk/tip/331.md).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`lset`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/lset.html) to update list stored in the array variable, along with building a new list for the 5th element with [`concat`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/concat.html) and [`lindex`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/lindex.html):

```
set sock abc
set comPorts($sock) [list $sock 0 0 1 {129} {} {} {} ]
set data {134 135}

lset comPorts($sock) 4 [concat [lindex $comPorts($sock) 4] $data]

puts $comPorts($sock) ;# abc 0 0 1 {129 134 135} {} {} {}
```

Comment: `[list [lindex $comPorts($sock) 4] {*}$data]` would also serve if you like the looks of that better.

Comment: That won't work correctly if `lindex $comPorts($sock) 4` already has multiple elements.

Comment: There is no advantage to using `lreplace` instead of `lset` in this scenario.

Comment: @SchelteBron Sure it will. `concat {1 2 3} {a b c}` -> `1 2 3 a b c`. It flattens out the lists.

Comment: Oh, were you thinking of something like `lset $comPorts($sock) 4 ...`? Yeah, that could work. Definitely shorter.

Comment: I was referring to your `[list [lindex $comPorts($sock) 4] {*}$data]` alternative. That doesn't work if `lindex $comPorts($sock) 4` has multiple elements. Sorry for not being clear.